# Visual Studio 2013 TFS Cache constantly corrupt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Every single day, multiple times a day, my Visual Studio TFS cache becomes corrupt. I get errors like this in VS:

[image]

The error is bogus because I can reach the TFS website and I can use the tools provided by the TFS Power Tools extension in Windows Explorer just fine. The real reason is because my VS TFS cache is being corrupted - if I close VS and delete the cache files manually, then re-open my project, I can access TFS from VS for a little while until the cache is corrupted again. Other team members don't have the problem. It is isolated to my machine (not caused by a TFS setting)

Does this happen to anyone else? Is there a way to fix it? I would rather not have to "Repair" VS as I will have to reinstall a bunch of other stuff and render an entire day useless.

Comment: I've read that some people have this problem because they use multiple versions of VS. I only use VS 2013.

Comment: When you say TFS cache files, do you mean files under: c:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\ ?

Comment: Yes, more specifically C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Comment: I have gotten this twice recently working with different versions of TFS and VSTS from VS2015.3. I have to delete the cache file at "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache" and let VS build a new one. My connections stay defined! I think a MSFT bug supporting different versions of TFS!

Comment: My problem was that we did not reset the guid on the cloned TFS server using the "TfsConfig ChangeServerId" command.

Answer (score 0):

You should first try a repair. It may be painful, but It is better than a rebuild.

It sounds like something on your machine is messing with Visual Studio...